# PayFlow integration using transparent redirect. Invalid Merchant or Merchant doesn't exist

Tags: paypal, payflowpro

I have a similar question like [PayPal PayFlow Pro with Transparent Redirect - User Authentication Failed Issues / Documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17635386/paypal-payflow-pro-with-transparent-redirect-user-authentication-failed-issues)

Problem occurs on step 5

Secure token request for the transparent redirect (https://pilot-payflowpro.paypal.com)

```
PARTNER=PayPal
&VENDOR=myAuthUserName
&USER=myAuthUserName
&PWD=myPassword
&CREATESECURETOKEN=Y
&SECURETOKENID=f6153d8b0c6c42c789e61daa7daa55b1
&SILENTTRAN=TRUE
&TRXTYPE=A
&CURRENCY=USD
&AMT=20
&RETURNURL=myReturnURL
&CANCELURL=myCancelURL
&ERRORURL=myErrorURL
```

Response:

```
RESULT=0&RESPMSG=Approved&SECURETOKEN=9u5CH4WMKOkey9pVTgSJBwAqG&SECURETOKENID=f6153d8b0c6c42c789e61daa7daa55b1
```

So it seems like the account authenticates correctly.

Next I send post to https://pilot-payflowlink.paypal.com with params

```
SECURETOKEN=9u5CH4WMKOkey9pVTgSJBwAqG
&SECURETOKENID=f6153d8b0c6c42c789e61daa7daa55b1
&ACCT=4111111111111111
&EXPDATE=12%2F15
&CSC=123
```

Response:

`Error: Invalid Merchant or Merchant doesn't exist!`

What can cause this problem?

PayPal Manager settings are:

```
Service Summary:
Hosted Checkout Pages  Test 
Payflow SDK/API (Full Access)  Test 

Transaction Process Mode: Test
AVS: No
CSC: No  
Enable Secure Token: Yes
```

Comment: fyi, you don't post to a pilot payflow link url. It is https://payflowlink.paypal.com for live and test transactions.

Comment: @Irina have you get any solution for above issue ?