# Paypal Payflow Pro SILENTTRAN redirect returns 200 and doesn't redirect

Tags: paypal

I'm trying to do PayPal Transparent Redirect (we are currently using Payflow Pro successfully, but would like to offload PCI stuff)...

I've seen the posting at: [Stack Overflow Transparent Redirect issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17635386/paypal-payflow-pro-with-transparent-redirect-user-authentication-failed-issues) and I am redirecting to the payflow-link. However, the browser then receives a 200 response and does not redirect back to my success, error or cancel page.

More detail:
I'm redirecting to () with the following form data (tokens and keys changed for security reasons):

```
<form name="PayPalForm">
      <input name="SECURETOKEN" type="hidden" value="changed" />
      <input name="SECURETOKENID" type="hidden" value="changed" />
      <input name="CARDNUM" type="hidden" value="4111111111111111" />
      <input name="EXPMONTH" type="hidden" value="07" />
      <input name="EXPYEAR" type="hidden" value="16" />
      <input name="CVV2" type="hidden" value="123" />
</form>
```

My setup send (to https://pilot-payflowpro.paypal.com):
TRXTYPE=S&TENDER=C&COMMENT1=Order ID: 80392&AMT=36.00&NAME=User Name&STREET=1234 E. 17th Street&CITY=Tucson&STATE=Arizona&ZIP=85711&COUNTRY=United States&RETURNURL=https://stage.mysite.com/index.aspx?sec=com&sub=buy&CANCELURL=https://stage.mysite.com/index.aspx?sec=com&sub=purchase&ERRORURL=https://stage.mysite.com/index.aspx?sec=com&sub=purchase&SILENTTRAN=TRUE&CREATESECURETOKEN=Y&SECURETOKENID=changed

Hmmm, could be the ampersands in the RETURNURL, etc parameters... I'll try url-encoding them?

Comment: I'm redirecting to: pilot-payflowlink.paypal.com as the mentioned article states.

Comment: URL-Encoding the URLs had no effect. I'm still just getting a 200 response and no redirect from paypal.  Looking at my reports in paypal manager, there are no transactions for today, so it's not going through.  What else do I need to do?